# Retrieve API data Microsoft Health Bot - Authorization error JWT verification failed

Tags: jwt, postman, microsoft-health-bot

I tried to retrieve the API data from Microsoft health bot by following this repo documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/HealthBotCodeSnippets/tree/master/HealthAgentAPI in which the GET API endpoint suppose to be `https://us.healthbot.microsoft.com/api/account/${tenantName}/scenarios`.


Where the JWT sign token should be:

```
{
  "tenantName": "myTenant", (tenant is from my Health bot portal)<br />
  "iat": "1648533033"  
}
```

(I put year of 2022, iat value I got from Unix Time Stamp: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

So I place the above tenantName and iat in the JWT website (https://jwt.io/)  to generate the JWT token.

On the Postman: I do `GET` request with the above endpoint and on the header tab, I place `Authorization` as KEY and the VALUE of `Bearer <JWT Token just generated>`.


The response was `Authorization error - JWT verification failed` 400 Bad request


Could anyone help spot any of my mistake?

Comment: I'm not familar with the ms-health-bot, but your token contains a claim `iat`, that is the time issued at (token creation timestamp). So maybe the validation fails because the iat timestamp is too far in the future. Try with current time instead. Again, it's just a guess. And with which secret did you sign the token?

Comment: @jps The solution was I didn't put the correct secret on VERIFY SIGNATURE, so you when Decoded you also need to put the correct secret value where you can find on MS Portal of your Health bot in <br />
Integration section > secret > API_JWT_SECRET 

Cheer, hope this answer help you too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was I didn't put the correct secret on VERIFY SIGNATURE when I was generating the JWT token, so you when Decoded you also need to put the correct secret value where you can find on MS Portal of your Health bot in 
Integration section > secret > API_JWT_SECRET

Cheer, hope this answer help you too.